# Is there a way *not* to persist a field with Siena

Tags: java, google-app-engine, siena

I use siena with google engine. 
I have a model class with a field (named `secret`) that I don't want to be persisted.
(I don't want the column to be created in the google datastore)

Something along the lines of

```
Class person {
   @Id 
   public Long id ; 

   public String name ; 

   @Ignore
   public String secret ;

}
```

The field `secret`has to be public.

Do you have any idea to achieve that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Java's transient keyword:

```
public transient String secret;
```

That should stop it from being persisted.

Comment: Damn, I shouldn't have looked it up and I would have beat you... +1!

Comment: Too bad there is not something Siena specific. Because now I can't serialize the "secret" field either. After all sometimes you may want to read data from your filesystem and not persist all of it. Then again you can create DTO...

Comment: There is change request on the siena project to add the @Ignore annotation. https://github.com/mandubian/siena/pull/24